# What's the shortest way to count substring occurrence in string? (Elixir)

Tags: string, elixir

Right now I have been using `Regex.scan` method:

```
Regex.scan(~r/do/i, “Do. Or do not. There is no try.") |> length
```

In Ruby, we can use `.scan` method: `"Hello world".count "o" #=> 2`

Is there a shorter method to count substring in a string with Elixir? No need for fancy regex, I just need to count how many substring in a string.

Comment: `String#count` in ruby works for single characters only. Your example in Elixir counts the number of substrings, in ruby one would do `String#scan` for that. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I'd be careful to not to equate "short" with "optimal".  I may be reading your question wrong but it seems as if you think that a shorter implementation is automatically superior--for some definition of "superior".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not shorter, but an alternative:

```
"Hello world" |> String.graphemes |> Enum.count(& &1 == "o")
```

Thanks to @mudasobwa for the idiomatic way.

Comment: In idiomatic Elixir that would be `"Hello world" |> String.graphemes() |> Enum.count(& &1 == "o")` :)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to split the string by the given substring, and then return the list length minus one

```
len = "foo bar foobar" |> String.split("foo") |> length()
total = len - 1
```